# Small Q on building a page on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

right now I'm creating a page contain a list which is updated by powershell on server side

And I wanna display the last time that powershell scripting ran, how can I get that?

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: does the script alway update something in the list? or could it run without updating any items at all?

Answer (score 0):

Upon your powershell operation you could write the date of last operation to a SPWeb property bag. On your page you just need to read that value.